# How to add data to a model without a form, in Rails5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Post model and I have created the migration `AddTotalVotesToPosts` to add column `total_votes` into table `posts`. I have the following code :

```
@post.total_votes=@post.votes.sum(:vote)
```

My question is how to add this data to the Post table? 
Please know that I am a beginner and I still struggle to understand Rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sound like what you want is an [association callback](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-callbacks) that fires when the record is added:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :votes, after_add: :update_total_votes

  def update_total_votes(new_vote)
    self.class.where(id: id).update_all(
      "total_votes = (SELECT sum(votes.vote) FROM votes WHERE votes.post_id = posts.id)"
    )
  end
end
```

This updates the post with the following query after the vote is created:

```
UPDATE "posts" SET total_votes = (SELECT sum(votes.vote) FROM votes WHERE votes.post_id = posts.id) WHERE "posts"."id" = $1  [["id", 1]]
```

You can update all the records by removing the WHERE clause:

```
Post.update_all("total_votes = (SELECT sum(votes.vote) FROM votes WHERE votes.post_id = posts.id)")
```

Comment: Yes I needed something like that.Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest to use counter_cache to your `Vote` model.

```
class Vote
   belongs_to :post, counter_cache: :total_votes
end
```

this will automatically update the `total_votes` for the particular post when new vote is created or deleted.

if you already casted votes for some posts before adding total_votes column then you can reset the counters for the posts in the following manner:

```
Post.find_each { |post| Post.reset_counters(post.id, :comments) }
```

Comment: If you're going to iterate through all the records at least use `.find_each` instead of pulling all the records into memory which will crash the server.

Comment: But I'm pretty sure the op wants something different than a cache_counter. Note the use of `sum` instead of count. Its the sum of votes.vote - not the count of the number of associated records that is important here.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may be neglecting to save your changes. After calling your code to set the total number of votes, call `@post.save`. This will actually record those changes in your table.

Comment: So I write my code in posts#create and save the changes. The problem is that when I modify or add a vote, the change doesn't go to the database.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. How sure are you that the save is working successfully? Have you seen the change successfully be saved in the console?